# Deleting a node from the start of a linked list

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am implementing a stack using a singly linked list where the Head is at the top of the stack and the Tail is at the bottom of the stack.

I am implementing a pop operation. In order to do this, I must make the head equal to the second node in the linked list. But before I do this, I need to delete the first node in the linked list first. I can do this using `delete head->next;`.

My question is, if I delete that first node, can I still use it to move on to the next node? Or is it bad practice to use a reference of a node that has had `delete` called on it. Here is the code I want to use to implement pop.

```
delete head->next;
head->next = head->next->next;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do:

`delete head->next;`

Then `head->next` is invalid.  If you try to dereference it in the next line (remember the right hand side will be evaluated *before* the assignment), your program will crash.

`head->next = head->next->!next; // dereference of the bad pointer happens where I put the !, and you crash there.`

If you want to delete the object at `head->next` you will need to save it off first.

```
p = head->next;
head->next = head->next->next;
delete p;
```

Comment: What exactly is `p`? Would you be able to type out the full declaration of p?

Comment: `p` is the same type of pointer as `head->next`.  I don't know the type because you didn't post it in your question, but if `next` is `foo *` then make `p` a `foo *`.  The compiler will complain if you do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

First, once something is deleted, it is gone. Don't access deleted memory.

Second, why are you saying `head->next = head->next->next`? Shouldn't `head = head->next` be good enough for pop? In a empty list, `head` would be `nullptr`, wouldn't it?

Third, why are you not using `std::list`?

Last, order of operation is sometimes important, especially when the linked list might be shared by multiple threads. This is how I'd implement pop (and optionally make it multithread safe):

```
void list::pop() {
  // optionally, acquire mutex
  node* to_be_deleted = head;
  head = head->next;
  if (head == nullptr) tail = nullptr;
  // release optional mutex here
  delete to_be_deleted;
}
```

Comment: In my hypothetical situation, `head` is a node that has a reference `next` to the first node in the linked list. Now that I think about it, you're right, `head` should simply be a pointer. I just have one question. After you call delete on `to_be_deleted`, is it INSTANTLY gone?